# Proof of Laplace expansion using minors

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, laplace-expansion

I've come across with the following proof of the Laplace expansion:

> Let
>
> $\Delta=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} a_{1j}\bar M_j^1$
>
> and
>
> $\tilde{\Delta}= \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}\bar M_j^i$
>
> We'll prove by induction that $\tilde{\Delta}=\Delta$.
>
> For a $2 \times 2$ matrix, clearly, it holds:
>
> $\tilde{\Delta_2}=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}\bar M_j^i=-a_{21}a_{12}+a_{22}a_{11}=\Delta_2$
>
> Suppose that for $n -1$ matrix $\tilde\Delta_{n-1}=\Delta_{n-1}$ is true. Then:
>
> $$\tilde{\Delta_n}=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}\bar M_j^i=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}\left(\sum_{k<j}(-1)^{1+k}a_{1k}\bar M_{jk}^{i1}+\sum_{k>j}(-1)^k a_{1k}\bar M_{jk}^{i1}\right) $$
>
> Gathering all the coefficients of $\bar M_{j_0k_0}^{i\,\,1}$
>
> $$j_0>k_0\colon\; (-1)^{i+j_0}a_{ij_0}(-1)^{1+k_0}a_{1k_0}+(-1)^{i+k_0}a_{ik_0}(-1)^{j_0}a_{1j_0}=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}(a_{ij_0}a_{1k_0}-a_{ik_0}a_{1j_0})=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}M_{j_0k_0}^{1\,\,i}$$
>
> $$j_0<k_0\colon\; (-1)^{i+j_0}a_{ij_0}(-1)^{k_0}a_{1k_0}+(-1)^{i+k_0}a_{ik_0}(-1)^{j_0+1}a_{1j_0}=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}(a_{ik_0}a_{1j_0}-a_{ij_0}a_{1k_0})=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}M_{j_0k_0}^{1\,\,i}$$
>
> $$\tilde{\Delta_n}=\sum_{j\ne k}(-1)^{i+j+k+1}M_{jk}^{1i}\bar M_{jk}^{1i}$$
>
> $$\Delta=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} a_{1j}\bar M_j^1=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} a_{1j}\left(\sum_{k<j}(-1)^{i+k-1}a_{ik}\bar M_{jk}^{1i}+\sum_{k>j}(-1)^{i+k-2}a_{ik}\bar M_{jk}^{1i}\right) $$
>
> Gathering all the coefficients of $\bar M_{j_0k_0}^{i\,\,1}$
>
> $$j_0>k_0\colon\; (-1)^{1+j_0}a_{1j_0}(-1)^{i+k_0-1}a_{ik_0}+(-1)^{1+k_0}a_{1k_0}(-1)^{i+j_0-2}a_{ij_0}=(-1)^{j_0+i+k_0}(a_{1j_0}a_{ik_0}-a_{1k_0}a_{ij_0})=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}M_{j_0k_0}^{1\,\,i}$$
>
> $$j_0<k_0\colon\; (-1)^{1+j_0}a_{1j_0}(-1)^{i+k_0-2}a_{ik_0}+(-1)^{1+k_0}a_{1k_0}(-1)^{i+j_0-1}a_{ij_0}=(-1)^{k_0+i+j_0}(a_{1k_0}a_{ij_0}-a_{1j_0}a_{ik_0})=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}M_{j_0k_0}^{1\,\,i}$$
>
> $${\Delta_n}=\sum_{j\ne k}(-1)^{i+j+k+1}M_{jk}^{1i}\bar M_{jk}^{1i}=\tilde{\Delta_n} ~~ \blacksquare $$

I just can't understand the part where they "gather coefficients":

$$j_0>k_0\colon\; (-1)^{i+j_0}a_{ij_0}(-1)^{1+k_0}a_{1k_0}+(-1)^{i+k_0}a_{ik_0}(-1)^{j_0}a_{1j_0}=\\
=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}(a_{ij_0}a_{1k_0}-a_{ik_0}a_{1j_0})=(-1)^{i+j_0+k_0+1}M_{j_0k_0}^{1\,\,i}$$

I'm okay with the $ (-1)^{i+j_0}a_{ij_0}(-1)^{1+k_0}a_{1k_0}$ part, which is simply what we get after plugging $j_0$ and $k_0$ into the previous formula of $\tilde{\Delta_n}$ (the sum of two sums) for a single and specific iteration. But where does the
$$(-1)^{i+k_0}a_{ik_0}(-1)^{j_0}a_{1j_0}$$
come from? I just can't see anything like this before $\bar M_{j_0k_0}^{i\,\,1}$.

I'm trying to figure this out for many hours and I'm completely lost. I would appreciate any explanation!

Comment: Just curious, which book is this proof from?

Comment: @Phonon - it is taken from wikipedia. I tried to find the same proof in books but with no success.

Comment: Everything of interest about determinants can be proved without such horrible formulas. What's the motivation for delving into them? No real surprise you couldn't find this in any book.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen - the question is not whether or not there are more elegant proofs of this theorem (obviously there are). I want to understand this specific proof, and I'm almost there. I just can't understand one nuance - everything else is pretty straightforward, albeit looks bulky.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\bar M_{j_0k_0}^{i\,\,1}=\bar M_{k_0j_0}^{i\,\,1}$$
Thus, you always have two different coefficients for the same minor that add up:
$$j=j_0 , k=k_0 ~~ (j_0>k_0): \\
j>k\colon\; (-1)^{i+j_0}a_{ij_0}(-1)^{1+k_0}a_{1k_0}\\$$

$$
j=k_0, k=j_0:\\
j<k\colon\;
(-1)^{i+k_0}a_{ik_0}(-1)^{j_0}a_{1j_0}
$$

Comment: So simple. Thank you!